# How to sum with javascript if data form while()?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code

```
<script>
function select(val, item)
{
var prize = $(".prize"+item).val();
var prize = prize*val;
$(".dollar"+item).html(prize);

//----- THIS CODE ERROR --------//
$sub_total=$(".dollar1").val()+$(".dollar2").val()+$(".dollar3").val()+..... etc;
$(".total").html($sub_total);
// ---------------------------- //

}
</script>

<input type="hidden" value="140" class="prize1">
<select class="quantity" id="quant2" value="1" onchange="select(this.value, 1)"> src="1">
<option value="1" selected>1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
prize : <span class="dollar1" value="140">140</span>
<br>
<input type="hidden" class="prize2" value="150">
<select class="quantity" id="quant2" value="2" onchange="select(this.value, 2)"> src="2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
prize : <span class="dollar2" value="300">300</span>

...... etc

<br><br>
<label> TOTAL </label> : <span class="total">?????</span>
```

How to make a total element , can compute all amounts on the price? How if I after onchange select, then on `dollar1 dollar2 dollar3 ... etc` will 
summed , because I use `while()` on this script. 
What should I do in this script ?

```
$sub_total=dollar1+dollar2+dollar3+..... etc;
$(".total").html($sub_total);
```

IF this php code

```
<?php
while($loll = $resultu->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
$id_item= $loll['id_item'];
$prize=$loll['prize'];
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prize ?>" class="prize<?php echo $id_item ?> ">
    <select class="quantity" value="<?php echo $id_item ?>" onchange="select(this.value, <?php echo $id_item ?>)"> src="<?php echo $id_item ?>">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    prize : <span class="dollar<?php echo $id_item ?>" value="<?php echo $prize ?>"><?php echo $prize ?></span>
    <br>
}
    ...... etc

    <br><br>
    <label> TOTAL </label> : <span class="total">?????</span>
```

> How i can summed `$sub_total= ALL --> $(".dollar<?php echo $id_item ?>")?`

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? I'm not seeing where your while loop is either.

Comment: You jQuery selector is referencing a class.that will give you an array of elements

Comment: if you look at the numbers 1 , 2 in class . it is the result of a database . I use while($loll = $resultu->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){ $id_item = $loll['id'];} and i put class="prize<?php echo $id_item;?> and onchange="select(this.value, <?php echo $id_item;?>)".. I do not enter the code php because it is not important

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery example that will run a sum calculation when the user changes the select elements:

**HTML**

```
<select id="select1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <select id="select2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input id="result" type="text"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select1, #select2').change(function () {
        var num1 = Number($('#select1').val());
        var num2 = Number($('#select2').val());
        var sum = num1 + num2;
        $('#result').val("$" + sum);
    });

});
```

Comment: What if the data is taken from while() ?so instead of just 2 select only?

Comment: I don't understand where this while loop comes into play.

Comment: Please create a fiddle so I can take a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aritabacan/ayzvtxfy/1/ 
but I do not know use the javascript at fiddle . but if tried on localhost , the script works .